# How do you check for a changing value within a string

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am doing some localization testing and I have to test for strings in both English and Japaneses. The English string might be 'Waiting time is {0} minutes.' while the Japanese string might be '待ち時間は{0}分です。' where {0} is a number that can change over the course of a test. Both of these strings are coming from there respective property files. How would I be able to check for the presence of the string as well as the number that can change depending on the test that's running.

I should have added the fact that I'm checking these strings on a web page which will display in the relevant language depending on the location of where they are been viewed. And I'm using watir to verify the text.

Comment: Are you asking how to build a regular expression to match them or how to identify the HTML element using Watir syntax?

Comment: I was hoping for a regular expression to ensure the correct text is showing but I have little experience with using them. At the moment I'm slicing the text and just looking for the leading text but this is not ideal for the test.
displayedText=get_string("text") 
if $osLocation=="jp"
  text=displayedText.slice(0..11)
    else
  text=displayedText.slice(0..25)
    end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read elsewhere about various theories of the best way to do testing for proper language conversion.

One typical approach is to replace all hard-coded text matches in your code with constants, and then have a file that sets the constants which can be updated based on the language in use.  (I've seen that done by wrapping the require of that file in a case statement based on the language being tested.  Another approach is an array or hash for each value, enumerated by a variable with a name like 'language', which lets the tests change the language on the fly.  So validations would look something like this

`b.div(:id => "wait-time-message).text.should == WAIT_TIME_MESSAGE[language]`

To match text where part is expected to change but fall within a predictable pattern, use a regular expression.  I'd recommend a little reading about regular expressions in ruby, especially using unicode regular expressions in ruby, as well as some experimenting with a tool like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test regexes

In the case above a regex such as:

`/Waiting time is \d+ minutes./` or `/待ち時間は\d+分です。/`

would match the messages above and expect one or more digits in the middle  (note that it would fail if no digits appear, if you want zero or more digits, then you would need a * in place of the +

Comment: That's the method that we were using in the beginning before we had to look at the Japanese version. I was hoping that there was another method to sort it out as new language support may be required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check for the literal string. Check for some kind of intermediate form that can be used to render the final string.

Sometimes this is done by specifying a message and any placeholder data, like:

```
[ :waiting_time_in_minutes, 10 ]
```

Where that would render out as the appropriate localized text.

An alternative is to treat one of the languages as a template, something that's more limited in flexibility but works most of the time. In that case you could use the English version as the string that's returned and use a helper to render it to the final page.